# Using LinearLayout to display a variable number of images

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout

In a LinearLayout, I am trying to display an integer number using images for digits.  I want the number to be centered and the images to scale depending on how many digits are present.

My initial layout with 2 digits:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<view
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <ImageView
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_digit_0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <ImageView
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_digit_0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is what it looks like.

A) With 4 digits, everything looks good, the digits fit horizontally and are as tall as possible vertically.

[image: 4 digits scaled to fit]

B) With many more digits, it still scales nicely to the available space.

[image: many more digits scale nicely]

C) But when the **LinearLayout** height is reduced, the 4 digits separate and  gaps appear between them.

[image: images have separated]

D) By removing the **layout_weight** from each **ImageView**, the 4 digits come back together.

[image: digits come back together]

E) But when the **LinearLayout** height is increased, the digits scale to the full height of the view and some vanish horizontally off screen.

[image: digits too large]

How can I have these digit images resize to fill the available space, show all digits and be centered without gaps, while retaining their scale proportions, regardless of the **LinearLayout** dimensions?

Thanks.

Comment: have u tried android:scaleType try its properties according to ur requirement

Comment: give fixed size of imageview!  use scaletype-

Comment: scaleType does not seem to work.  fitXY stretches or squashes the images so their proportions change scale.  Fixing the image sizes requires code calculations which vary with the number of digits.

Comment: try with   android:scaleType="centerInside" and android:scaleType="fitCenter"

Comment: I have tried all the scaleType values including: center, centerInside, centerCrop, fitCenter, fitEnd, fitXY and matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding scaletype?

```
<ImageView android:scaleType="scaleXY" android:src="@drawable/my_image"/>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Comment: is scaleXY exist in scaleType?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Comment: No, its just an example. See scaletypes: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I've tried various combinations of android:scaleType but none of them seem to work.  Using **fitXY** causes the digits to stretch out of scale.

Comment: Have you tried with android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I found the answer.

For the 2nd **LinearLayout**, change the **android:layout_width=** from "**match_parent**" to "**wrap_content**".  Then add **android:layout_gravity="center"**.  This allows the **LinearLayout** to shrink to its contents when smaller height forces the digits to shrink.  When it shrinks, though, it also centers itself in the containing view.

Thanks for the input everyone.